# Python Code Review / Annotation Tool

Tags: python, code-review

I'm returning to Python after a few years, and I'm trying to build up a good suite of development tools.  I'm  little out of date, so I thought I would ask.

I'm after a code review tool - or at least a tool where we can host discussions in parallel with the code and linked to it.

We are using gitolite and PyCharml.

So far the best option looks like Upsource (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/discussion-comments.html).

Can anyone improve on this?